# Coupons not adding in Prestashop (Checkout Page)

Tags: javascript, html, task-parallel-library, e-commerce, prestashop-1.7

When I am applying coupon during checkout in prestashop, it is not working (on clicking Add Button, nothing is happening).

However, when I am removing a product from Cart and then applying coupon by clicking Add Button, it is working.

I tried every way, but it is not resolving, need your kind support in resolving this.

**Below Screenshot is when coupon is code is not applying:**

[image]

**Below Screenshot show, coupon code added successfully, when changes made in cart:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a bug in your HTML. Kindly go once through the same or share the HTML Code

Answer (score 0):

This is not a mistake in creating your coupon? Number of use? limited to certain product?

Try to create another one with no restriction but a r

Regards